# Hangfire multiple "failed" queues?

Tags: hangfire

Right now all job failures go to a single `Failed` queue. Is it possible to configure Hangfire to have multiple failed queues? For example a `Retail Order` job processor errors would go to a `Retail Order Failure` queue, while errors from a `Mail Order` job processor would go to a `Mail Order Failure` queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact they don't go in failed queue, in hangfire that kind of structure does not exists. They get new state see [IState](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/main/src/Hangfire.Core/States/IState.cs) DeleteState, SucceededState etc.

On dashboard itself these failed jobs are just filtered out by [IMonitoringApi](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/main/src/Hangfire.Core/Storage/IMonitoringApi.cs). So right now it not possible to do that since IState is crucial for tracking progress of the job and persisting state - not sure what road map of hangfire looks like in future ?!